# Multiple filter selection with checkboxes only works with 1 selection

Tags: php

my multiple selection filter with checkboxes only works with 1 selection made on the checkboxes. This only counts as there are made multiple selections within the same column of the table. The multiple selection filtering does work on cross columns within the same table.

im using the following construction:

```
$where = ' WHERE TRUE';
$opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts'])? $_POST['filterOpts'] : array('');

if (in_array("medewerker", $opts)){
$where .= " AND medewerker = 1 ";
}  
if (in_array("medewerker1", $opts)){
$where .= " AND medewerker = 2 ";
}
```

I have already tryed to change the code to the following that does seems to work but only limited to 2 selections:

```
if (in_array("medewerker", $opts)){
$where .= " AND medewerker = 1 OR 2";
}  
if (in_array("medewerker1", $opts)){
$where .= " AND medewerker = 2 ";
}
```

As soon as I change it to '1 OR 2 OR 3' then the filter disables completely.

Comment: I think what you're doing is not what you really want to do. true OR whatever is always true. So 2 OR whatever is also always true since 2 is non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
$where = ' WHERE FALSE ';
$opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts'])? $_POST['filterOpts'] : array('');

if (in_array("medewerker", $opts)){
    $where .= " OR medewerker = 1 ";
}  
if (in_array("medewerker1", $opts)){
    $where .= " OR medewerker = 2 ";
}
```

To work without filters use this

```
$opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts'])? $_POST['filterOpts'] : array('');
if (empty($opts)) {
    $where = ' WHERE TRUE ';
} else {
    $where = ' WHERE FALSE ';
}

if (in_array("medewerker", $opts)){
    $where .= " OR medewerker = 1 ";
}  
if (in_array("medewerker1", $opts)){
    $where .= " OR medewerker = 2 ";
}
```

Comment: This indeed works, only the list starts empty and the filter adds them on the screen individualy. It should be that before any filters are checked all the results must be visible and when using the checkboxes then then the rest should dissapear.

Comment: Uhm this does not let the data appear on the screen withouth the filter being used.

Comment: Did you try the second part of my answer?

Comment: Yes the first part works great for filtering, the only issue is that the screen starts with no data. So only after you use the filter then the results show on the screen. I need it to show the data on the screen before the filter is used and with the filter then filter out the results.

Comment: To overcome that, I have used the second part, not sure why it is not working. Can you please use the second part and print the query. The query is supposed to have only `WHERE TRUE` as the condition when no filter is applied.

Comment: I tryed to print the query with echo $where; but there was no result on the screen for that.